# How to remove existing values from an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller, hidden-field

In this script I select checked id and store string in hidden field.
For removing exist id I have stored string in array.
I want to remove exist id from array and store array values into
hidden field.

Script:

```js
AddRemoveCustomer = function(){
    $(".checkBoxClass").click(function (e) {
        //var CustomerIDArray = '';
        var hidCID = document.getElementById("hfCustomerID");
        var CustArray = [];
        if(hidCID!=null || hidCID!=undefined)
        {
            var CustID = hidCID.value;
            CustArray = CustID.split("");

            alert('CustID is :' + CustID );
            alert('CustArray is :' + CustArray );
            if (CustID == null || CustID=="") {
                $(".checkBoxClass:checked").each(function () {
                    alert("Null");
                    //CustomerIDArray = $(this).val();
                    //alert(CustomerIDArray);
                    alert('value : '+$(this).val());
                    hidCID.value = $(this).val();
                });
            } else {
                alert("Not Null");
                //CustomerIDArray = CustID;
                $(".checkBoxClass:checked").each(function () {
                    alert($(this).val());
                    //CustomerIDArray = CustomerIDArray + "," + $(this).val();
                    //alert(CustomerIDArray);
                    CustID = CustID +","+ $(this).val();
                    alert(CustID);
                    alert('value : '+$(this).val());
                    hidCID.value = CustID;
                });
            }
            //CustID = CustomerIDArray.values;
        }
        //$('#hfCustomerID').val(allSelectedValues);
        //alert($('#hfCustomerID').val());
    });
};
```

Comment: You are not concatenating the individual values. Instead you just overwrite `hidCID.value` in every iteration. Use some delimiter and concatenate. Also be aware that `split("")` will split a string in individual characters. You need a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

To remove array item use [Array.splice(startIndex, deleteCount)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control).

```
let elIndex = custArray.indexOf(deleteId);
custArray.splice(elIndex, 1);
```